# Unix grep for Java logs

Tags: java, grep

I am new to Unix grep and i would like some help to come up with a grep command.

Currently, i have the following types of error in my application logs:

> 2012-02-31 10:21:41,333 ERROR [65] (GeneralAppliancesBean.java:135) -
>   Exception java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
>
> 2012-01-31 10:24:41,843 ERROR [41] (FlightStatusBean.java:135) -
>   Exception java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out
>
> 2011-01-31 10:22:41,841 ERROR [1] (FlightCancellation.java:135) -
>   Exception java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection timed out
>
> 2011-01-31 10:22:41,841 ERROR [1] (OrderBean.java:132) -
>   Exception java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection timed out

I would like to know the timestamp (e.g. `2012-02-31 10:21:41,333`), the Java class and lineresponsible (e.g. `GeneralAppliancesBean.java:132`) for this exception.

How can i build this grep command?

Comment: This question really belongs on superuser ... there is no programming involved.

Comment: I think this belongs on serverfault.  Also should do this with awk, not grep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shadyabhi@archlinux ~ $ echo '2012-02-31 10:21:41,333 ERROR [65] (GeneralAppliancesBean.java:135) - Exception java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed oot' | cut -d "," -f 1
2012-02-31 10:21:41
shadyabhi@archlinux ~ $ echo '2012-02-31 10:21:41,333 ERROR [65] (GeneralAppliancesBean.java:135) - Exception java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed oot' | cut -d " " -f 5
(GeneralAppliancesBean.java:135)
shadyabhi@archlinux ~
```

`cut` is better suited for this.

If your logs are in file named logs, use this.

```
while read myline 
    do
        echo "Date: "$(echo $myline | cut -d "," -f 1)
        echo "Error: "$(echo $myline | cut -d " " -f 5)
    done < logs
```

If the errors are multiline (which I am skeptical about):

use `grep "ERROR" logs | cut -d "," -f 1` for date & `grep "ERROR" logs | cut -d " " -f 4` for class and line number.

Comment: If i put it into a grep statement, does it look like this: grep -rn "ConnectionException|SocketTimeoutException" * | cut -d "," -f 1 cut -d " " -f 5 ?

Comment: @ChinBoon Are you sure, your errors are multiline or it's just the terminal width putting sometext in next line?

Comment: @ChinBoon If the errors are multiline (which I am skeptical about), use `grep "ERROR" logs | cut -d "," -f 1` for date & `grep "ERROR" logs | cut -d " " -f 4` for class and line responsible.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep ERROR java.log|awk '{print $1 $4}'
```

Comment: NOOOO not grep + awk!  Just do  awk '/ERROR/ {print $1 $4}'

Comment: I agree that awk is better suited than grep from what you describe so far. One note - since the date/time stamp is actually 2 fields (especially as awk sees it) the print needs to be '{print $1 $2 $5}'

Comment: LOL. My bad. Force of habit. Never got into awk since I found perl.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an alias for searching for multiple keywords at the same time, eg

```
alias finderrors="grep -i -w 'fatal\|error\|exception\|timeout\|waiting\|fail\|unable\|lock\|block'"
```

and then use it this way

```
finderrors mylogfile.log
```